# textElements and buttons move when i press a button

Tags: css

I am working on a project and im trying to make a game,

For context: i have 2 items on my screen and you need to guess whats worth more, i have a more or less button, when that button is clicked my textelement(`.questionText2`) moves down and my `valueIndex` and `valueIndex2` move up/down, also my buttons move up and down when i press them, it only happens when my value appears on the screen, here is my code:

```
 <h2 id="question-text" class="question-text"> 
        <span class="items" data-item-name="${item2.name}">${item2.name}</span> 
      </h2> 
         <h2 id="question-text2" class= "question-text2"> 
            <span class="itemsz" data-item-name="${item1.name}">${item1.name}</span> 
         </h2> 
   <h3 id="valueIndex"> 
            <span class="value">${item2.value}</span>  
        </h3> 
        <h3 id="valueIndex2"> 
            <span class="value">${item1.value}</span>  
        </h3> 
        <div class="buttons"> 
            <button id="more"> 
                More  
               </button> 
               <button id="less"> 
                Less 
               </button>
```

```
 .question-text {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 104;
  font-size: 3rem;
  width: 50vw;
  height: 60vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 0;
}
.question-text2 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 104;
  font-size: 3rem;
  width: 50vw;
  height: 0vh;
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 0;
  left: calc(50vw + 1rem); 
  top: 35%; 
}

    .buttons{ 
  width: 50vw;
  position: absolute; 
  top: 70%; 
  left: 10%; 
  transform: translate(38%, 250%); 
  z-index: 103; 
  left: calc(50vw + 1rem); /* Adjust the value as needed */
  top: 39%; /* Adjust the value as needed */
} 
    #valueIndex { 
  position: relative;
  z-index: 104;
  font-size: 3rem;
  width: 50vw;
  height: 60vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 0;
} 
#valueIndex2{ 
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 104;
  font-size: 3rem;
  width: 50vw;
  height: 0vh;
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 0;
  left: calc(50vw + 1rem); /* Adjust the value as needed */
  top: 35%; /* Adjust the value as needed */


}
```

, my `item1.name` and `item2.name` are not centered when the game starts, neither are the `valueIndex`es, the price is not visible at the start only when you click a button it displays,

is there any way of the making it so they dont collide if thats a problem, without having to redo everything?

maybe the only way would be to wrap the value,buttons,question-text in one div? but that messes all up

Comment: I couldn't understand the question at all. The question should be clear and concise. Try to remove code that is useless to the question and only include the code that is useful, point out what you've tried and what you expect

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to do similar work like this

```js
        const itemAButton = document.getElementById('itemA');
        const itemBButton = document.getElementById('itemB');
        const valueA = document.getElementById('valueA');
        const valueB = document.getElementById('valueB');

        itemAButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
            alert('You selected Item A');
        });

        itemBButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
            alert('You selected Item B');
        });

        // To reveal the values when clicking the buttons:
        itemAButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
            valueA.classList.remove('hidden');
        });

        itemBButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
            valueB.classList.remove('hidden');
        });
```

```css
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
        }

        .container {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            height: 100vh;
            text-align: center;
        }

        .question-text {
            font-size: 2rem;
        }

        .value {
            font-size: 2rem;
        }

        .buttons {
            margin-top: 20px;
        }

        .hidden {
            display: none;
        }
```

```html
    <div class="container">
        <h2 class="question-text">
            Which item is worth more?
        </h2>
        <div>
            <button id="itemA">Item A</button>
            <button id="itemB">Item B</button>
        </div>
        <h3 id="valueA" class="hidden">
            Item A Value: <span class="value">100</span>
        </h3>
        <h3 id="valueB" class="hidden">
            Item B Value: <span class="value">200</span>
        </h3>
    </div>
```